# TikTok Post Video API | Something went wrong Error

Tags: api, backend, tiktok

We are trying to publish a video from backend API.

We have successfully generated auth code from which we have derived `access token` and `open-id`.

After which, we hit the following end-point to post the video as suggested in the official documentation:

```
https://open-api.tiktok.com/share/video/upload/?open_id={open-id}&access_token={access-token}
```

The video is successfully posted because we get the `"share_id"` in response.

For example, last video uploaded gave following response:

```
{
    "data": {
        "err_code": 0,
        "error_code": 0,
        "share_id": "v_inbox.7116721364874266670"
    },
    "extra": {
        "error_detail": "",
        "logid": "202207051356180100040030077350020041FD8C568"
    }
}
```

As soon as the API is hit, we receive a notification on the mobile app that the video:

```
"Your video was sent to TikTok: We'll notify you when it's ready."
```

After a while, the following notifications is received:

```
"Your video from Snatchit is ready: Edit your video before sharing it to TikTok"
```

Please note: "Snatchit" is the name of the app which we have integrated.

This is where the problem arises, when we hit on this notification, we are getting the following error:

```
"Something went wrong. Try again."
```

Can someone suggests what is wrong with it?

Someone suggested that it is the region issue in the following post:
[Can't post videos to Tiktok using the Web Video Kit API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70012013/cant-post-videos-to-tiktok-using-the-web-video-kit-api)

However, I have tried it with different countries from my phone and it still gives the same error.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you,

Regards,
Shameel Uddin

Comment: It is a region issue, and more about where the account was registered. We've seen issue if the user creates the account in certain regions, creates via desktop instead of mobile, etc. As a test, try creating a new account via mobile in the U.S. (VPN). It will likely work.

Comment: I have tried all of these steps:
1. Connected my phone with US VPN.
2. Created account from my mobile phone.
3. Create a VM instance on cloud. Used Postman to hit the API.

I am still facing the same issue.

Comment: The only other thing to try is upgrade the account to business within the app. After that you can contact the TikTok platform team with the issue: https://developers.tiktok.com/doc/getting-started-faq/

Comment: @ShameelUddin I know this is an old question, but facing this issue currently. What was the solution for you?